# JQM 1.4 redirect user to page on app loaded

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a jquerymobile 1.4 application that has all the pages on the same html page (pages are broken into different divs).

What I'm looking for is an app-level initialiser event to subscribe to that allows me to do some logic checking (e.g. authentication status) and redirect them to a login page (say div#login) if necessary.

I've explored working with a popup, setting the login page to be dialog="true" and what I'm stuck with is how to redirect the user when the app first loads.

There's mobileinit and pagecontainercreate events. If I subscribe to the pagecontainercreate event then I can run a changePage function and that works, but then it transitions to the default page straight afterwards anyway.

As far as the ideal lifecycle:

mobile app finished loading -> show login dialog page -> init login page

What's happening now is:

pagecontainercreate -> show login dialog page -> close login dialog page and show home page automatically.

Comment: you will need to use [`pagebeforechange`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)

Comment: Omar, that web page is amazing - thank you. I implemented your demo, but it's still flashing with the initial page first.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Can you post your code?

Comment: var x = false;
            $( document ).on( "pagebeforechange" || "pagecontainerbeforetransition" , function(e, data) {
                var toPage = data.toPage[0].id;
                if(!x) {
                    x = true;
                    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#login");
                }
            });
It looks like it's firing the event multiple times (as per your documentation). Is it best to put on a "one" binding?

Comment: Yea, you need to catch first `pagebeforechange`. I have better example, let me find it. Check this http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-prevent-jquery-mobile-page-navigation/

Comment: Btw, use `pagebeforechange` only.

Comment: That works well - thanks so much. The page and app life cycles of jquerymobile was driving me insane and it's been really helpful to see it laid out in those diagrams on your site.